# yii2 check database type (mysql or oracle)

Tags: yii2

In my project I want to make utility class for different databases (MySQL, Oracle). How can I determine what db type is using in current \Yii::$app->db object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
Yii::$app->db->getDriverName();
```

to get the name of the current DB driver.